# Описание методов своего класса

Tags: qtcreator

В Java для Андроид можно давать описание своим методам/функциям в виде /**Описание*/, причем оно поддерживает формат RTF. В том же QtCreator тоже можно поднести мышку к методу и прочитать его описание, что делает и для чего он. Собственно вопрос: как это сделать для своих методов?